custom maven install in pluginManagement
I have a pom where I am overwriting the default install with a custom install execution:
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-install</id>
          <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>custom-install</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>install-file</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <configuration>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-customName.jar</file>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

I want to put this in a parent pom or mixin pom so I can use the same execution in a more modular way. The pom where this lives does not build or install any jar.
The issue is that when I build the parent pom/mixin pom, I get the following error:
The specified file '<file path with respect to the parent pom>' not exists
I don't expect the path in <file> to exist in the parent pom. I only want the  path to be resolved when another pom tries to execute it.
